# Какая разница между puts и printf или gets и scanf?

Tags: c

Какая разница между `puts` и `printf` в языке Си? А также между `gets` и `scanf`?

Comment: Ну... большая. Они по меньшей мере делают разные вещи. Что именно вас интересует?

Comment: puts выводит переданную строку и символ новой строки, а printf - генерирует выводимую строку на основании строки формата и дополнительных данных. Если коротко. gets читает строку (но об этой функции забудьте, это большая ошибка, а не функций), а scanf - выполняет анализ считываемой строки и записывает вводимые данные в переменные в соответствии со сцецификацией.

Comment: А при чём тут типы данных?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартная C функция `printf` - это функция форматированного вывода. Используя ее вы можете задавать ширину поля, количество выводимых символов, выравнивание по левому или правому краю поля. Вы можете задавать одновременно несколько выводимых данных разного типа для одного вызова функции.

Стандартная функция `puts` - это функция не форматированного вывода, предназначенная для вывода только одного аргумента, имеющего тип указателя на строку (ее первый симол). Фактически, вызов `puts` эквивалентен следующему вызову функции `printf`

```
puts( s );
printf( "%s\n", s );
```

где `s` - это указатель на некоторую строку.

То есть функция `puts` выводит строку, пока не встретится завершающий ноль, и после этого выводит в поток также символ новой строки.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает некоторые возможности использования функции `printf` в сравнении с функцией `puts`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Hello World!";

    printf( "\"%20s\"\n", s );
    printf( "\"%-20s\"\n\n", s );

    printf( "\"%20.5s\"\n", s );
    printf( "\"%-20.5s\"\n\n", s );

    int width = 20;
    int size = 5;

    printf( "\"%*.*s\"\n", width, size, s );
    printf( "\"%-*.*s\"\n\n", width, size, s );

    printf( "\"%*.*s %s\"\n\n", size, size, s, "user246831" );

    printf( "%s\n", s );
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
"        Hello World!"
"Hello World!        "

"               Hello"
"Hello               "

"               Hello"
"Hello               "

"Hello user246831"

Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Как видно из программы, можно задавать размер поля и количество выводимых символов во время выполнения программы при использовании функции `printf`. Однако ничего этого нельзя сделать используя функцию `puts`.

Что касается функции `gets`, то она не безопасная и может привести к переписыванию памяти за пределами символьного массива, используемого в качестве аргумента функции. Поэтому она больше не поддерживается стандартом языка C. Вместо нее рекомендуется использовать функцию `fgets`.

Функция `scanf` - это функция форматированного ввода. Используя ее, вы можете задавать некоторые условия ввода, аналогично тому, как это имеет место с функцией форматированного вывода `printf`. Более подробно об этой функции вы можете узнать из ее описания в документации или непосредственно в стандарте языка C.